# Static struct linker error

Tags: c++, static, struct

I'm trying to create a static struct in C++:

```
static struct Brushes
{
  static HBRUSH white ;
  static HBRUSH yellow ;
} ;
```

But its not working, I'm getting:

```
Error 4 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct HBRUSH__ * Brushes::white"
```

Why?

The idea is to be able to use `Brushes::white`, `Brushes::yellow` throughout the program, without having to create an instance of `Brushes`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to define the static members somewhere, usually in the .cxx file, e.g.:

```
HBRUSH Brushes::white;
```

The reason is that the header file doesn't make the definition, it only declares it.

Comment: The definition has to be in one translation unit, but it could get into one through header files as well.

Answer (score 6):

You should remove the first `static` from the `struct Brushes` line. Then you will need to define the initial values (and declare their memory) in a .cpp file as following:

```
HBRUSH Brushes::white(some_init_value);
HBRUSH Brushes::yellow(some_init_value);
```

Comment: If you're using VC++ you can have these declarations go in the header file (instead of .cpp) if you include __declspec(selectany).  Pretty cool trick.

Answer (score 2):

So you need:

```
HBRUSH Brushes::white = xxxx;
```

somewhere in one of your source files. And get rid of that initial static.

you do know about the stock objects in Win32 GDI, right?