# Weird linker error with static std::map

Tags: c++, static, dictionary, std

Why do I get linker error when I try to compile this in Visual Studio 2008

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

class MyClass
{
public:
 MyClass () { };
 virtual ~MyClass() {};

 static std::string niceString (std::map<int, int> mappp) { _myMap = mappp; return "nice string"; };

private:
 static std::map<int, int> getMap ( ) { return _myMap; };

 static std::map<int, int> _myMap;
}; 

int main(){

 std::map<int, int> mappp;

 mappp[1] = 1;

 std::cout << MyClass::niceString(mappp);

}
```

error is:

```
Error 1 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class std::map<int,int,struct std::less<int>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<int const ,int> > > MyClass::_myMap" (?_myMap@MyClass@@0V?$map@HHU?$less@H@std@@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBHH@std@@@2@@std@@A) test22.obj test22
```

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Static struct linker error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850809/static-struct-linker-error) amongst others.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Defining static members in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536372/defining-static-members-in-c)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You've declared the static member `_myMap`, but not defined it.  Add this line just above `int main()`:

```
std::map<int, int> MyClass::_myMap;
```

Think of it like a function that has been declared but not defined in any .cpp file - you get a linker error if you use it.

Comment: is this also needed if I have another static variable, e.g. std::string myString ?

Comment: I think you did not mean " but not defined it", but instead "but not initialized it"

Comment: 2019, and that mistake still don't prompt a more specific error message in Visual Studio...