# What library contains map STL collection?

Tags: c++, stl, shared-libraries, lnk2001

I'm trying to compile a project, but when I include a map object, it gives me a LNK2001 error.  I've included the correct header file, but I don't know what the library is that I should be including.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008, and when I set "Ignore All Default Libraries" to "No" it will work, but having the properties set that way isn't an allowed option for the final outcome.  I thought there would be some sort of all-STL library, but I have vectors and dequeues in my code, and they work fine.  It's only when I add in a map object that the error shows up.

Comment: "having the properties set that way isn't an allowed option for the final outcome" That seems like a problem you should fix.

Comment: Could you show us the smallest compileable code example which exhibits this problem, as well as the exact errors you get?

Comment: I agree, but that's not something I have control over. :-/  And TommiT's code is pretty much it, I'm not doing anything with the map yet, just trying to declare it is causing trouble.

Comment: Can you post some of the code that is giving you trouble? Details about the linker error would help, too.

Comment: What is the **EXACT** error message. std::map should only require header files so there is something else wrong that you are not telling us.

Comment: If it's static, you need to  put t in a cpp file.


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585069/weird-linker-error-with-static-stdmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a friend had a similar problem, and the library I needed was msvcprt.lib .

Answer (score 1):

The correct include should look like that:

```
#include <map>
```

And the correct initialization of map should look something like that:

```
std::map<int, char> mymap;
```

Comment: Yeah, I've already got that.  Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably an optimization in the STL implementation -- code that is not dependent on any template parameter is split off into a base class, so only a single copy is used across all instances, and this copy is kept in the C++ standard library, so you will not be able to avoid linking against this library.